# Permission denied for relation <table_name>

Tags: postgresql, privileges

So I'm making this app and I'm using Postgres and I've already created a database, a user and a password and granted all privileges on the database to the user I've created.

The thing is, when I switch the database in psql using `\c <database_name>` I get in just fine and can use queries on it.

But when I run `psql` using `postgres://user_name:password@localhost:5432/databasename` on terminal and try to `select * from the <table_name>` it gives me this message

> permission denied for relation <table_name>

Can you please tell me what to do, I've had this problem before and I had to create another database or change the user but I want a better solution please.

PS: I've tried to use this :

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON TABLE <table_name> to <user_name>
```

This is how I created and accessed my database:

```
rawan95=# create database food ;
CREATE DATABASE

rawan95=# create user meal with password '123';
CREATE ROLE

rawan95=# grant all privileges on database food to meal;
GRANT

rawan95=# \c food
You are now connected to database "food" as user "rawan95".
```

After that, I've built it using

```
food=# \i src/database/db_build.sql
BEGIN  
DROP TABLE  
CREATE TABLE  
INSERT 0 1  
COMMIT
```

Then I selected data from the table just fine, but when I try to access it using this, I get an error: psql `postgres://meal:123@localhost:5432/food`

```
food=> select * from foods;

ERROR:  permission denied for relation foods
```

Comment: `\c <database_name> ` uses the same user as the previous connection. Whereas `psql postgres://user_name:password@localhost:5432/databasename` uses a **different** user - so apparently you did not grant all needed privilege to the second user

Comment: So next time I create a database I should not access it using \c, instead I should directly use this: `psql postgres://user_name:password@localhost:5432/databasename` , then run my `\i db_build.sql` to create my tables, right?

Comment: You can use `\c` but you also need to specify the user you want to change to `\c databasename user_name`

Comment: I've tried it and this is what I got: rawan95=# \c food meal  &&&&&&& 

FATAL: Peer authentication failed for user "meal"  

 &&&&&&& Previous connection kept

Comment: I worked it out using this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/820792/peer-authentication-failed-for-user-with-all-privileges-in-postgres-9-5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are granting the privileges *before* you create the tables. 
As there are no tables at that moment nothing is granted. The tables you created are not owned by the user `meal` but the user `rawan95` (which the `\c` command told you).

Plus: granting "all privileges" on a database, does not grant any select privilege. [As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-grant.html) "all privileges" are: CREATE, CONNECT, TEMPORARY, TEMP.  The CREATE privilege would allow the user `meal` to create tables in that database.

If you want all those tables to be **owned** by the user `meal` you need to run your setup script after you connected as the user `meal` (the `\c` command did not change the current user)

If you do want `rawan95` to be the owner of the tables, you need to either grant the select privilege **after** creating all tables:

```
grant select on all tables in schema public to meal;
```

Or, you can change the default privilege *before* creating the tables (before running `db_build.sql`), so that they are applied to all tables in the future:

```
alter default privileges in schema public
  grant select on all tables to meal;
```

The `alter default privileges` only has an effect for tables that are created **after** that. So to fix your current setup, you need to first grant select on the existing tables, and the change the default privileges for all tables that are created in the future.

Comment: I've done what you said and then ran this \d and it still shows rawan95 as owner. And I wanna ask for next time how do I access the database with the username I've made for it?

Comment: Of course it still shows that as the owner if you did not drop the tables and re-created them after connecting as `meal`, e.g. `psql -U meal -h localhost -d food`

Answer (score 1):

Have you granted usage on the schema? Without that the table permissions are useless.

```
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA schema_name TO username
```

EDIT: Based on comment thread below we have established.
The table is in public schema.
The table belongs to rawan95 but the schema does not (public schema belongs to root postgres user).
The OP is attempting to connect and access the table as user 'meal' they have granted table permissions using the rawan95 user but are unable to grant schema permissions.

From the above, the problem could still be that the user 'meal' does not have usage on the public schema. If you are on Linux the quickest way to sort this is to switch to the super user to make this change from terminal:

```
sudo -u postgres psql -c "GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO meal"
```

FURTHER EDIT - having read your new clarification this is not correct (or at least not useful). The issue is as pointed out by the other answerer that you didn't have a table at the time you did the grant.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to this so could you  please explain what the second schema should be, does a schema have a name or what exactly

Comment: Yes, the schema will have a name, the default schema name is 'public'

Comment: So I've done what you said and I got this:
WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "public".
then this in the next line: GRANT

Comment: That probably means the user you are using to set the permissions doesn't have permission to set them. Are you connected as the owner of the schema? By default this is the user called postgres

Comment: I don't know how to know the user name, I've created a database and gave it a user and it all went well and when I use these lines it's all fine:
rawan95@Sha3nona:~/Foods(database)$ psql
.
rawan95=# \c food
You are now connected to database "food" as user "rawan95".
===========
food=# \i src/database/db_build.sql
BEGIN
DROP TABLE
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 5
COMMIT
=============
food=# select country from foods;
here it shows the results I want, but it stops working when I write the database url and use it to access the database.

Comment: Can you add this to your question as it's difficult to read the code in comments? Sounds like adding permissions to the public schema failed because you're not the owner of that schema, but that's a red herring as you are probably inside your user's own schema, which will be called the same thing as the user (use the command  \dn in psql to list all schemas). In any case, if you are using the same user in both instances I'm not sure what's going on, perhaps there's a syntax mistake in the one that isn't working.

Comment: In fact, please can you just run \d in psql and share the output

Comment: This is the output :
food=# \d
             `List of relations
 Schema |     Name     |   Type   |  Owner  
--------+--------------+----------+---------
 public | foods        | table    | rawan95
 public | foods_id_seq | sequence | rawan95
(2 rows)`
 Even though I've craeted a user and granted all privileges to it and it said GRANT, so Idk what's wrong.

Comment: Ok, so we've established that the table is in the public schema and the table is owned by rawan95 (although the schema is not) . When you try to use the URL are you using rawan95 user or another one?

Comment: I've edited the question, and yes I'm using the user I've created for this database it's called meal, but why does it automatically go to rawan95 even though I've created a user for it? and I've granted all privileges to the user I've crated so what's wrong?

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me, the answer below you worked just fine, but you were a great help, thanks again <3